Sign Discrepancy in Propagator for Dirac equation
I am reading Bjorken and Drell's textbook on relatistic QM (page 94) and this one section is holding me back.
I have no issue showing that the propagator for the Dirac equation is $S(x';x)=\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m}{p^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m^2}e^{-ip_{\mu}(x'^{\mu}-x^{\mu})}$ (where $ (\gamma^{\mu} \hat{p_{\mu}}-m)S(x';x)=\delta^4(x'-x) $ ) However, when the text discusses the case of the advanced propagator (i.e. $t'>t$) they state $S(x';x)=-i\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-iE(t'-t)}e^{-ip_{i}(x'^{i}-x^{i})}\frac{\gamma^{0}E+\gamma^{i}p_{i}+m}{2E}$ (where $i$ only runs over $1,2,3$). However, I can not find any rationale for the $-$ sign out front.
From what I see they take the residue at $p^0=E=\sqrt{p^i p_i+m^2}$ which should amount to replacing $p^{\mu}p_{\mu}-m^2$ in the denominator with $2E$ and replacing $p^0$ with $E$ elsewhere, finished with an additional factor of $2\pi i$. This should yield $S(x';x)=i\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{-iE(t'-t)}e^{-ip_{i}(x'^{i}-x^{i})}\frac{\gamma^{0}E+\gamma^{i}p_{i}+m}{2E}$
Sorry if this is somewhat stupid too post about but finding other references has proven surprisingly difficult. Any help greatly appreciated.


Bjorken and Drell do not compute the advanced propagator but the Feynman propagator $S_F(x^\prime-x)$.

In the case of Feynman boundary conditions, the pole (in the complex $p^0$-plane) at $p^0=\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$ is circumvented by a small semicircle in the upper half-plane and the pole at $p^0=-\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$ by a small semicircle in the lower half-plane.

Concentrating on the relevant part of the integral, $$\int \frac{dp^0}{2\pi} \frac{e^{-ip^0(t^\prime-t)}}{(p^0)^2-\vec{p}^2-m^2} \ldots,    $$ we have to distinguish the cases $t^\prime-t \gt 0$ and $t^\prime - t \lt 0$.

For $t^\prime-t \gt 0$ we have to close the path in the complex plane by a large semicircle in the lower half-plane such that the exponential damping factor $e^{- | {\rm Im} \, p^0| (t^\prime-t)}$ ensures a vanishing contribution from the large semicircle. Note that the closed path is thus taken clockwise, i.e. in the negative mathematical sense (explaining the minus sign). Only the pole at  $p^0=\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$ contributes and one arrives at the result
$$\frac{-2\pi i}{2\pi} \, \frac{e^{-i \sqrt{\vec{p}^2 +m^2} (t^\prime -t)}}{2 \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}} \ldots=-i \,\frac{e^{-iE (t^\prime-t)}}{2E} \ldots .$$ Obviously the Feynman boundary conditions (only positive frequencies contributing for $t^\prime-t \gt 0$) are fulfilled.

In the case $t^\prime-t \lt 0$, the large semicircle must be taken in the upper half plane and the explicit calculation is left as an easy homework exercise.



It’s been so long since I’ve used the residue theorem I completely forgot about that curve orientation matters—I was dumbfounded as to where the - came from. Thanks so much!
